# Setting array size though constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I am trying to create a array and set its size by using a constructor. This is my code:

```
public static class Node<T>{
   public T data;
   public Node<T> next;
   public Node(){

   }

   public Node(T data, Node<T> next)
   {
      this.data = data;
      this.next = next;
   }
}

Node array[];

public WordStoreImp(int n){
    Node =  new Node[n];
}
```

I create the initial class of a Node and then create a array of them, and then pass in the size of the array through the constructor but this does not seem to be working for some reason. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: You mean `array = new Node[n];`?

Comment: This works for me - thanks for the help